# How to convert a java made game for pc to android without any external framework?

Tags: cross-platform

How to convert a java made game for pc to android manually ie without any external framework like libgdx?
For example games like minecraft and limbo were originally made for pc only but later they got released for other platforms also, how do they do it?
Where can i learn more about porting games across multi platforms?

Comment: What is this eternal "without external framework"? External frameworks save time and effort. Sometimes they change a task from "nearly impossible" to "could be done".

Comment: This attitude won't get you the sympathy of this community... Your question could be closed as "too broad", so don't be a jerk to users trying to help your by asking for more details.

Comment: Ok i am sorry, i just wanted some answers instead of somebody just bragging about why i shouldn't learn about it

Comment: We see a never-ending parade of people who want "no external frameworks". It seldom goes well for them because that's not how game development is done. So if you want to learn real game dev, you will use external libraries and frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porting games can be a painful process. You essentially need to rewrite large parts of the game, mainly the rendering and the input part, as they completely depend on the platform. Depending on the platforms you may be able to keep some of your code, but it's not guaranteed. You may end up deleting the complete rendering part of your code and start from scratch.

The actual game-logic code can be reused, as it should be platform independend. To simplify porting to other platforms I would encourage you to cleanly separate logic code from rendering code to make porting easier.

If you are using a pre-made game engine you may be lucky and it already supports multiple platforms, reducing the needed effort to port your game significantly.

There is no other way than rewriting the incompatible parts.

Also take a look at this: [Cross-platform independent development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3621/cross-platform-independent-development?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, are there any resources from where i can learn how to port games across cross platforms?

Comment: @ZxcCxz Totally depends on the technology your are using. And there is no standard way to go about the porting of a game. You essentially have to learn programming for both platforms and finally translate your program to the other platform.

Comment: I don't get why this was downvoted? I know the question has issues (I flagged it as too broad myself), but I also tried to clear some of the apparent confusion OP has about the process of porting games, which was too long for a comment.

Comment: This is why i get mad here...